# Cursor doesn't work using cursor url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Second example work, the hand did show up, but why the first `div` doesn't work?

```css
div {
  cursor: url('http://i.imgur.com/EuDeZWn.png'), auto;
}

span {
  cursor: url('http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif'), auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  target
</div>
<br>
<br>
<span>
  target 2
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property):

> In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms.

You image is 237 x 173, which is significantly larger.